# JS / Jquery script Help, its not looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

so here is the script:

```
<script>
var div = $("#gridline1");
$(document.body).mousemove(function(e){ 
if(e.pageX<630){div.animate({right:'+=1'},1);}
else {div.animate({left:'+=2'},1);}
});
</script>
```

Its working, but when it gets after the "else" its stop doing the "if" statement.
Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/nxaFG/

Comment: There's no loop in this code.  What exactly do you expect to happen here?  After executing either the `if` block or the `else` block, this handler should finish.  Though I'm not sure how animations (which take time) will work on the `mousemove` event...

Comment: Please add the DOM to your fiddle. There is no #gridline1 it could select - nothing will animate.

Comment: It seems that to increment left and right doesn't work in this case. I don't know why, i'm sorry. Why don't you just decrease the left value at the if block like so http://jsfiddle.net/7UCxc/ ?

Comment: @sofl your solution works, at least in Chrome. just make sure you are moving the mouse far enough to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what HTML or CSS you are using, and the effect may depend on those as well. However, I think you can just replace `right:'+=1'` with `left:'-=1'`. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/katylava/kagnr/

Comment: @lavallee Yep, thats pretty much solve the problem, THANK YOU ! :)